# Convert a string into HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Suppose I regex a string in Javascript and save it in a var.

So my string would be something like :

```
var reg= "<html><body>..... </body></html>"
```

or only

```
var reg= "<body>....</body>
```

How do I make this string into HTML document that I would be able to display somewhere from a Javascript function.

Comment: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

```
var win = window.open('');
win.document.write(reg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `document.write()`. You can use this command to output string that can be a html element or even a javascript code, or css etc.

Sure that you can try things like that:

```
document.write("<body><div>a</div></body>");
```

Then you transform your whole page into that.

Or even can you write in a `iFrame` or a `Window`, `Dialog`...

```
newWindow = window.open("");
newWindow.document.write("<body><div>a</div></body>");
```

**...**

```
newDialog = window.openDialog("");
newDialog.document.write("<body><div>a</div></body>");
```

I tried with the `iFrame` but i didnt found the write function into it, unhappily. But you can create element using `var div = document.createElement("div")` for example and after that you can `.appendChild(div)` in the `iFrame` easily this way:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.id = 'iFrame';
var stringElement = "div";
var div = document.createElement(stringElement);
iframe.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

You have too `window.showModalDialog()` but i dont know how it works kk.